# Missing equation in coordinate system transformation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I want to transform a differential equation from polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ to the following $(u, v, \phi)$ coordinate system:

$$
u = r \cos(\theta - \phi) \\
v = r \sin(\theta - \phi) \\
\phi = \theta + \arctan(\dot r,\ r\dot\theta)
$$

$u$ and $v$ form a rectilinear coordinate system aligned with the direction of motion along the $u$-axis.  Put another way, $\phi$ is heading, $u$ is distance from the origin along the track, and $v$ is cross-track distance from the origin.  (The reason I want to use coordinate system is numerical accuracy.)

I know that adding a variable means I need to add an equation, and I have a differential equation for $\phi$:

$$
\dot \phi = -\frac{\dot v}{u}
$$

I'm also using the following substitutions:

$$
r = \sqrt{u^2+v^2} \\
\theta = \phi + \arctan(u, v)
$$

---

The problem comes when I try taking the derivatives of $r$ and $\theta$:

$$
\ddot r = 
\frac{u\ddot u + v\ddot v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} + \cdots
\\
\ddot \theta = 
-\frac{v}{u}\frac{u\ddot u + v\ddot v}{u^2+v^2} + \cdots
$$

Both of them contain a multiple of $u\ddot u+ v\ddot v$.  Therefore I can't solve for both $\ddot u$ and $\ddot v$ (in fact the equations are inconsistent, so I can't even get one in terms of the other).

Is there something about my choice of coordinate system that is causing problems, or is it just my method of substitution?

### Update

I think I've figured out part of the problem.  I can set up two equations for $r$ and $\theta$ in terms of $u$, $v$, and $\phi$, and I can set up four more for the first and second derivatives.  Plus, I can add one more for $\phi$ as a function of $\theta$, $r$, $\dot r$ and $\dot\theta$.  This gives me seven equations.

I need to solve for $\ddot u$, $\ddot v$, and $\dot \phi$ to set up my differential equation.  I also need to solve for $r$, $\theta$, $\dot r$ and $\dot theta$ to eliminate them from the final equations.  This uses up all seven of my equations.

However, there is still a $\ddot\phi$ floating around. I can try to solve for it by taking the derivative of $\dot\phi$, but it contains $\ddot u$ and $\ddot v$; and when I substitute it into the expression for $\ddot v$ I end up with $\ddot v = \cdots + \ddot v$, which is false.  **What is another way to get $\ddot \phi$ that avoids this problem?**

Comment: What's r with dot on top? Derivative?

Comment: @Jack Derivative with respect to proper time $\tau$.

Comment: Well, for a start, from your third and sixth equations you have: $\arctan (u,v)=-\arctan (\dot{r},r\dot{\theta})$, and therefore $(u,v)=-(\dot{r},r\dot{\theta})$. Is that something that makes sense?

Comment: @Demosthene Check my geometry on this, but $\arctan(\dot r,\ r\dot\theta)$ should be the angle from $\hat\theta$ to the velocity vector, and $\arctan(u,\ v)$ should be the angle from $\hat u$ (which is along the velocity vector) to the position vector (which has the same direction as $\hat\theta$).  So that equation should be true.